# How to determine if a package was installed via develop or install commands

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am developing a Python package. Sometimes, I want to use the latest development version, sometimes I want to use the release version.  I am very lazy so want whatever I call to tell me whether or not it is a development version or a release version.

So, once a python package is installed, is there a way to determine whether it was installed using

```
python setup.py develop
```

or

```
python setup.py install --user
```

For argument's sake, let's assume that the package only has a console entry point.  I could check that the package is under `$HOME` like so:

```
if os.environ['HOME'] in os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)):
        print("⚠  You might be using the development version")
```

This works fine if the install command was `python setup.py install` but not if installing it locally.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @PeterWood: Finding out if a package install is the development version or the release version from within the console script.

Comment: Is this in general or for a particular package? There are conventions which aren't enforced.

Comment: @PeterWood: I have a released version installed. I have a development version that I work on and off on -- Yes, context switching sucks. I do not want to have to type "prog -v" every time I run it 'cause I am very lazy. Of course, if I were clever, I'd use virtualenvs... But that could be a good answer. ^_~

Comment: virtualenvs are brilliant, but i'm not sure they would help in that case. The only difference is that you wouldn't be mixing up your system packages and your project packages. You still have to know which version you're using i suppose.